# Android Cannot save image to mysql database

Tags: php, android

I don't know if someone could read all of this and give his time but anyway
I'm trying to save image into mysql database using android apps, but it fails , nothing is added, so i tryed to display some variables i use to save the image, in order to see if anything is going wrong so using the Log.d methode i display two variables, please see their content and help me to figure out where is the problem :

**MainActivity**

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
            Log.i("UploadImage ----- ",uploadImage);
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, data);
            Log.i("Result *****: ", result);
            return result;
        }
```

*String uploadImage* :

> 9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB...ect

*String result*: this variable shows a balise html br :

```html
<br />
```

**RequestHandler :**

```
public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        } else {
            response = "Error Registering";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

the problem is one sendPostRequest Methode but i cannot find it someone could find what is the problem there ?

this is script php i use :

```html
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  
  require_once('dbConnect.php');
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)";

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
  
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  
  $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
  
  if($check == 1){
   echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
  }else{
   echo "Error Uploading Image";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
  echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: what is data type of image in mysql db BLOB? and be sure that image you are trying to upload doesn't have bigger size than db allowed.

Comment: yes it is Blob Type, and i already save an image using a HTML form, but when it comes to the apps and with the same image something goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

1- compare image's data size and data size of BLOB type

```
  $image = $_POST['image'];

  $image = base64_decode($image );
```

and since you encoded the image before sending it to db, you need to decode it before store.